# Function to compare different files

Tags: c, file

I've written a function that compares two different files and it prints if they're equal or not. The problem is that the files are the same and at some point it returns as FAILED.

This is the function that I have:

```
void comparar_conteudo(){

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){

        int bp = 0;
        char ficheiro1[100] = "saida/command";
        char ficheiro2[100] = "expected/exp_query";

        char commandString[2]; sprintf(commandString, "%d", i);

        strcat(ficheiro1, commandString); strcat(ficheiro2, commandString);
        strcat(ficheiro1, "_output.txt"); strcat(ficheiro2, ".txt");

        FILE *novoFile1 = fopen(ficheiro1, "r");
        FILE *novoFile2 = fopen(ficheiro2, "r");

        char* line1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
        char* line2 = malloc(sizeof(char));

        while(fgets(line1, 1024, novoFile1)){

            fgets(line2, 1024, novoFile2);

            if(strcmp(line2,line1) != 0){
                bp = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(bp == 0)
            printf("Query %d: SUCCESS\n", i);

        else
            printf("Query %d: FAILED\n", i);

        fclose(novoFile1);
        fclose(novoFile2);
        free(line1);
        free(line2);
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Query 1: SUCCESS
Query 2: SUCCESS
Query 3: SUCCESS
Query 4: SUCCESS
Query 5: FAILURE
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can't find the problem so I would be thankful if you could help me!

EDIT:

If I ask to print what both lines have it returns like this:

```
Query 1: SUCCESS
Query 2: SUCCESS
Query 3: SUCCESS
Query 4: SUCCESS
13108172;LeonardoCoelho71950;29

13108172;LeonardoCoelho71950;29
13108172;LeonardoCoelho71950;29

Query 5: FAILED
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Note that `char commandString[2];` will overflow when you `sprintf` the value `i=10` into it.

Comment: You allocate one byte of memory and then read up to 1024 bytes into it. That’s not ok.

Comment: You haven't checked that the files are opening. And at the least, print out the filenames that you have pieced together, to check they are correct.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so should I increase the size?

Comment: If your only goal is to test if the files are identical then you could use hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you did this

```
    char* line1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char* line2 = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while(fgets(line1, 1024, novoFile1)){
```

all bets are off

you allocated `line1` as one byte, then read 1024 bytes into it. At least

```
    char* line1 = malloc(1024);
    char* line2 = malloc(1024);
```

Comment: You are correct! That was the problem. I still need to understand better the memory allocation of c, it seems that I don't use it very well

Comment: @HugoNovais The problem is that C is very unforgiving. Malloc gives a pointer to the start of the memory it allocated, there is no protection to prevent you running off the end and writing all over the next 1023 bytes that you dont own. This is exactly what happened. Try running your old program (the failed one) using valgrind

Comment: @HugoNovais the other huge clue was the `double free corrupt` message at the end, this is the system saying "boy bad things happened"